# how to count elements in a 2D array matching min and max in javascript for calculating histogram

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, histogram

I have a 2D array `DATA` in javascript and want to calculate a histogram. I have the bins already in place as a 1D array `my_bins`.

Is there an easy way to calculate, for each bin in `my_bins`, how many entries are in total in `DATA`that matches between `my_bins[i]-d`and `my_bins[i] +d`. I want to calculate across the 2 dimensions in `DATA`.

I'm using mongodb, in case this is important for the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: what do the two dimensions in your DATA array represent?  What does your one dimension in my_bins represent?  Why the different naming convention?

Comment: first dimention in `DATA` are the days, and second dimention are specific user values. so I have for each day and all users values.

Comment: the bins are the clases which I need to make the histogram. they represent the values on `DATA`